# If statement, sessions variables

Tags: php, session, time

The following code is within an ajax call. I'm trying to make sure people don't vote on questions with a certain id too often using sessions.

So they click a button, which executes the following php code:

```
  $id=$_GET["id"];


if ((isset($_SESSION["$id"]) && ((time() - $_SESSION["$id"]) > 180)) || (!isset($_SESSION["$id"]))) {
    // last vote was more than 3 minutes ago
    $_SESSION["$id"] = time(); // update/create vote time stamp


    //there is code here to add the vote to the database
}
else{
echo "sorry, you've already voted recently";
}
```

So I'm creating a session variable for each question id which holds the `time()` of their last vote. I would do this with cookies, but they can be disabled.

Currently, there is a bug somewhere with my logic, because it allows the user to keep clicking the button and adding as many votes as they want.

Can anyone see an error that I have made?

Comment: What's to prevent people from just deleting/not accepting the session cookie?

Comment: oh, thanks guys, didn't know about this, what would be a better idea for identifying the user? It doesn't need to be incredibly secure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. using sessions to prevent multiple voting makes very little sense.
2. sessions do use cookies with the same drawbacks
3. unlike strings, variables in PHP should be addressed without quotes. such a false usage WILL cause an error someday.
4. I see no point in checking for `isset($_SESSION[$id])` twice.
5. There was a bug in PHP which disallowed numerical indices for the $_SESSION array. Dunno if it was corrected nowadays.
6. As it was pointed out by Sajid, you have to call session_start() before using $_SESSION array.

now to the logic.
to me, it seems the code won't let anyone to vote at all. as it won't pass `isset($_SESSION[$id])` condition for the first time and won't let `$_SESSION[$id]` to be set and so on.

it seems correct condition would be

```
if ( (!isset($_SESSION['vote'][$id]) OR (time() - $_SESSION['vote'][$id]) > 180) )
```

Comment: You are my favourite person in the world right now! A lesson to all **"There was a bug in PHP which disallowed numerical indices for the $_SESSION array."** is indeed correct. I simply appended a character to the start of the `$id`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call [session_start()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php) to start the session before any headers are sent. Otherwise, sessions will not be enabled unless the ini setting to autostart sessions is on. Also, your server must be correctly configured to be able to store session files (usually a writable tmp dir is needed). See more about sessions here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.session.php

Comment: Thanks sajid, i've used sessions on the server before and i've started the session in index.php.

Comment: @JoeRocc you have to run `session_start()` on *every* page that uses sessions, not just `index.php` (unless, as Sajid mentioned, session autostart is enabled).

Comment: oh! thanks, but depressingly, it still adds a vote whether the user has already voted or not... any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

There might be a problem with the if statement. Try the following

```
$id=$_GET["id"];


if (((isset($_SESSION[$id]) && ((time() - $_SESSION[$id]) > 180))) || (!isset($_SESSION[$id]))) {
    // last vote was more than 3 minutes ago
    $_SESSION[$id] = time(); // update/create vote time stamp


    //there is code here to add the vote to the database
}
else{
    echo "sorry, you've already voted recently";
}
```

Comment: thanks ralfe, i've tried this and unfortunately, it hasn't changed anything... :/

Comment: Ok, well what I would do to debug would be the following:

    $a = isset($_SESSION[$id]);
    $b = time() - $_SESSION[$id];
    echo "($a && $b > 180) || !{$b})";

Then see the 'rendered' if statement expression and perhaps something will become apparent?

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps time() returns milliseconds and you should compare to 180000 instead of 180.

Comment: Perhaps one have to verify their guess with manual before answering?

Comment: this is not "ideas out of nowhere" site this is questions and answers site.